# android thread/handler in Touchevent

Tags: android, multithreading, graphics, touch-event

This touchevent is giving me a whole list of problems.. this is pure graphical and I have another thread running at the very same time while receiving info from the UI.

anyways I'm trying to run a method while your finger is held down on the screen.

so I'll just simplify my coding ALOT.

```
// global up top
boolean finderdown;
//... lots of code
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
{ 
    HoldingDown(event.getX(), event.getY(), heightf, widthf);
}

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
{ 
    HodlingDown(event.getX(), event.getY(), heightf, widthf);
    fingerdown = false
}

//.. lots of code


public HoldingDown Click(final float x, final float y, final float height, final float width)
{
    Thread myThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(fingerdown==true);
            {
                // class object = new class() in the activity area
                object.function(x ,y , height, width);
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
}

// manages Threads messages
private Handler threadHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
           // handle message
    }
};
```

I run something like this and it seems to be speeding up my other thread??

Comment: where is your problem buddy...

Comment: the thread just isn't executing.. I need it to continually run till you lift your finger.  It works on my phone but not my tablet.. not b/c of the code.. but b/c a still finger seems to always register as ACTION_MOVE on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are creating a new thread each time you are touching your screen and also you are making `fingerdown` false in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` but where are you turning it true.

I suggest you to make `x, y , width, height` as instance variable and control the execution of code inside thread by making `fingerdown` true or false in event code.

Try using below code

```
boolean var = false;  //instance variable to check if thread has started running for first time
int x, y, width, height; // variables as instance variables
boolean fingerdown;

Thread myThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(fingerdown==true);
            {
                // class object = new class() in the activity area
                object.function(this.x ,this.y , this.height, this.width);
            }
        }
    };

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
{ 
    this.x = event.getX();
    this.y = event.getY();
    this.width = widthf;
    this.height = heightf;
    fingerdown = true;


    if(!var){
       var = true;
       myThread.start();
    }
}


if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
{ 
    fingerdown = false
}
```

So instead of each time creating new thread in touch down event uou only make boolean true and false and control execution of code.

Comment: I'm going to try that when I get back.  The boolean error was just my typing on stackoverflow (had to edit my code so it wasn't thousands of lines).  Hopefully this works.. will be extremely appreciative.. (fingers crossed)

Comment: wouldn't take.. doesn't like the fact that I'm trying to pass an instance variable into my function.  Keeps hinting at the fact that variables should be declared inside new Thread()